# Run .NET Core application with specific angular configuration

Tags: angular, .net-core

I have .NET Core application with frontend in Angular. I want to run my app with specific configuration and host. When I add to package.json in scripts

```
"start": "ng serve --configuration=myconf--host myhost",
"build": "ng build --configuration=myconf"
```

I can run my app with `dotnet run` and everything is ok, but I dont want to change `start` and `build` in my package.json. Can I do sth like

```
"start": "ng serve"
"start:myconf": "ng serve --configuration=myconf --host myhost",
"build": "ng build" 
"build:myconf": "ng build --configuration=myconf"
```

in my package.json and specify configurstion and host in Command Line? I have tried `dotnet run start:myconf` or `dotnet run --configuration=myconf --host myhost` but it doesn't works.
Can I do this in another way?

Comment: Is this for development only? How is the .net core app providing the access to the angular app?

Comment: Yes, i want to use this locally only for development.

Comment: are you using the dotnet new angular project template with UseSpa()? How is that block of code configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my purpose it was enough to run `ng build --configuration=myconf --host myhost` in angular app, and then run my app with `dotnet run`. Nothing needs to be edit in package.json.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `dotnet new angular` template then you can change the spa script.

```cs
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
    // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start:myconf");
        // spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
    }
});
```